# Flow charts with lots of nodes

Tags: interaction-design, info-visualisation, flowcharts

I have a flow chart component with lots of nodes and it's overwhelming for the user to be blasted with it at once.

There are approximately 100 nodes in the flow chart. I like that it gives an overview of the entire flow chart - but it's really messy.

I've thought of adding a fixed window, scrollbar, and radar to know where they are. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to present flowchart with lots of items?

Comment: Can it be broken down into sections, so you have an overview chart that you can zoom into? 100 is not that bad, compared to some I've seen with thousands of nodes (Investment Bank month-end processing).

Comment: Can you make any generalizations as to how interconnected and complex the charts are? For example, are they often 100 nodes, but mostly down or across the page with little branching?  Or is there tons of branching, and the charts go all over the place?

Answer (score 1):

You can present a view from 10000 meters that shows the complete flow chart and that lets navigate to certain parts of the flow chart by clicking the point at which the viewport will be centered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think it's still a bit overwelming. I'm wondering whether we could skip using a flowchart and perhaps use a tree view instead. Thoughts?